# C# - abstract method parameter, specifically set for classes implementing it

Tags: c#, abstract-class, encapsulation

I want to implement a class which stores different appearances for different controls.
At first I thought to use generics, as such:

```
public class Appearance<T where T : Control> { ... }
```

but there are two problems. First of all, I want to use these appearances in a list for different controls, namely different T (impossible in this case). Secondly each control type's appearance will have different properties according to the control it is refering. So the solution is a base class (preferably abstract) and derived classes for each control type:

```
abstract class Appearance { ... }
public class TextBoxAppearance : Appearance { ... }
public class ComboBoxAppearance : Appearance { ... }
```

My problem now is that I would like to achieve encapsulation regarding the control types, each class concerns, namely:

```
public abstract class Appearance {
    public abstract void updateAppearanceOf(Control control);
}
public class TextBoxAppearance : Appearance {
    public void updateAppearanceOf([here I want to give TextBox instead of Control])
    {
        // implement update of TextBox
    }
}
public class ComboBoxAppearance : Appearance {
    public void updateAppearanceOf([here I want to give ComboBox instead of Control])
    {
        // implement update of ComboBox
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which technology?  Winforms, WPF and web have varying levels of support for styling / themes.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your issue is with the generic solution, so forgive me if you've already explained why you can't do this. But basically, keep Appearance as generic as you said, then when you inherit from Appearance in each of your derived (e.g. `TextBoxAppearance`) you specify your T when you inherit.

Comment: If you're using WPF, this is probably not the right direction to head in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your base class explicitly implement IAppearance

```
public interface IAppearance
{
    void updateAppearanceOf(Control control);
}
public abstract class Appearance<T> : IAppearance where T : Control 
{
    void IAppearance.updateAppearanceOf(Control control)
    {
        if (control is T) updateAppearanceOf((T)control);
    }
    public abstract void updateAppearanceOf(T control);
}
public class TextBoxAppearance : Appearance<TextBox> {
    public override void updateAppearanceOf(TextBox control)
    {
        // implement update of TextBox
    }
}
```

This way all the classes implementing the abstract `Appearance` just have to worry about how to handle their control.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a similar pattern to the `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable(T)`.

```
public interface IAppearance
{
    void Update(Control control);
}

public interface IAppearance<in TControl> : IAppearance
    where TControl : Control
{
    void Update(TControl control);
}

public class TextBoxAppearance : IAppearance<TextBox>
{
    void IAppearance.Update(Control control)
    {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;

        if(textBox == null) return;
        this.Update(textBox);
    }

    public void Update(TextBox control)
    {
        // Logic
    }
}
```